# Problem deploying list template (stp-file) by feature

Tags: list-template

I have a List template (a stp-file). If I upload it to the list gallery through the UI, it is uploaded and I can create lists based on that template file in the same site.

However, if I bundle it in a module in my project, and try to upload it, the file is added to the gallery, but I can't create lists with the definition! Not through UI, and not programmatically.

I use [this method](http://www.pranavsharma.com/blog/2010/05/06/stp-uploaded-by-feature-doesnt-appear-on-create-page/) to upload the file to the list template gallery.

My Elements.xml is as follows:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Url="_catalogs/lt" Name="ListTemplates" Path="ListTemplates">
        <File Url="MyList.stp" Path="MyList.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
            <Property Name="Title" Value="MyList" />
            <Property Name="Language" Value="1033" />
            <Property Name="FeatureID" Value="{3A71B642-D88C-48A4-BEB7-FC8DD4EFF9FE}" />
        </File>
    </Module>
</Elements>
```

Update: I want to add that I created a new list template based on a new custom list, and tried to deploy it the same way, but it didn't work either. So it's not the template file that's corrupt, it's something with the method

Comment: Is the locale for your site something other than English (US)?

Comment: Nope, it's english. When I upload it through the UI, it also takes the language value of 1033.

Comment: I want to add that I created a new list template based on a new custom list, and tried to deploy it the same way, but it didn't work either. So it's not the template file that's corrupt, it's something with the method.

Comment: Is the site template the same between the origin site and the one where you are deploying? A template created in a team site won't work in a non-team site, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Please view this
Add a module named as stp (Or whatever you want).
The module should look like as follows:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="stp" Url="_catalogs/lt" Path="">
    <File Path="stp\DesignLibrary.stp" Url="DesignLibrary.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists ="TRUE" >
      <Property Name="Title" Value="DesignLibrary" />
      <Property Name="Language" Value="1033" />
      <Property Name="Version" Value="4" />
    </File>
</Module>
```

In my view no need to use

because List template itself set feature id.
If you add the above property, It will add your stp in List template but you will not be able to use as template while creating list/library using this template.
It will not be available in creation webpart.
[Link](http://asharepointsolutions.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Have a [look](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2009/01/10/SharePoint-2007-Deployment_3A00_-Module-Features.aspx) at this for more details.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Url="_catalogs/lt" Name="ListTemplates">
        <File Url="MyList.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
            <Property Name="Title" Value="MyList" />
            <Property Name="Language" Value="1033" />
            <Property Name="FeatureID" Value="{3A71B642-D88C-48A4-BEB7-FC8DD4EFF9FE}" />
        </File>
    </Module> 
</Elements>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I need the Path="ListTemplates" in the Module, or else I can't activate with  error message ""MyList.stp" not found"

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried adding the name of the module in front of your **Path** attribute in the *File* tag?

Like so:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Module Url="_catalogs/lt" Name="ListTemplates" Path="ListTemplates">
        <File Url="MyList.stp" Path="ListTemplates\MyList.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary" IgnoreIfAlreadyExists="TRUE">
            <Property Name="Title" Value="MyList" />
            <Property Name="Language" Value="1033" />
            <Property Name="FeatureID" Value="{3A71B642-D88C-48A4-BEB7-FC8DD4EFF9FE}" />
        </File>
</Module>
```

Explanation [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21165/pagelayouts-deployed-through-feature-module-cannot-be-found/21166#21166)